# OSX vs Vim: a war for the Function keys

Tags: keyboard, macvim

Is there a way to quickly toggle the "use F1, F2, etc as standard function keys" in OSX? I'm a vim user on a MacBook, and I'd like to use at least some of the function keys for vim mappings, but it's a big sacrifice in ease-of-use outside of Vim.

How do most people resolve this?

Comment: i also use vim but i have never had to use one of the Fx Keys, what functions do they have which are not also mapped to other key-combos?

Comment: @konqui that's a good point. I was mapping a few things to Fx keys for convenience (help, toggle background light/dark, some other random stuff), but I'm not sure how helpful it actually is. I've since moved it all out of the Fx keys except for help (defaults to F1) and toggle background (F2). Both of these are easily available elsewhere, so I'm not sure it's worth the trouble. Palua is pretty cool though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Palua](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12)

Palua lets you set the 'standard function keys' setting for *individual* apps only.

> With Palua, you just need one click - or one hotkey - to toggle the mode your Fx keys are.

[image: Palua Smart Mode]

### [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>FunctionforF4</name>
    <identifier>FunctionforF4</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, KeyCode::F4</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

For other keys have a look at the [key list](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data).